# Finding cause of Long Task in Chrome DevTools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, performance-testing

I'm trying to track down the cause of a long task (>12s) in Chrome DevTools.  While the page loads, my CPU usage spikes to 100% over what appears to be 2 or 3 threads.

I've run a performance recording, and the long task shows an endless waterfall of "animation."  The animation segment doesn't have any more data for Summary / Bottom-Up / Call Tree / Event Log.

I tried checking Perfetto but when I save the profile, I get a JSON file with no data and 0kb size.  The console returns an error of "Failed to save timeline: Invalid string length (RangeError)."  I believe this is because of the insanely large recording.

Is there a better way to track down what's stressing the CPU?  Or how to identify more specifically what the long task is (not just "animation")?  Or perhaps a way to break down the recording so it can actually export?

Comment: Is this your application? Where does it run on? Whose machine spikes to 100% CPU, your own PC because of the browser? 

What's stressing the CPU comes with a greater understanding of the entire infrastructur and the types of HTTP requests you do.